# react-native link react-native-image-picker throws "(assets || []).map is not a function" error

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker, react-native-linking

I get the following issues when I attempt to add react-native-image-picker to my project.

```
$ npm install react-native-image-picker --save 
npm WARN @babel/plugin-check-constants@7.0.0-beta.38 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.38 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN aws-amplify-react-native@0.2.19 requires a peer of graphql@0.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-document-scanner@1.4.2 requires a peer of react-native@0.49.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-number-format@4.0.6 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8 (node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8 (node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})

+ react-native-image-picker@0.28.1
added 1 package from 4 contributors in 12.728s
```

And when I attempt to link I get the following error

```
react-native link react-native-image-picker 
Scanning folders for symlinks in /opt/app/dev/prescribedjobs/node_modules (22ms)
rnpm-install ERR! ERRPACKAGEJSON No package found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

(assets || []).map is not a function
```

Comment: Run **npm install** once again. Sometimes dependencies do not install properly. If it doesn’t work then delete node modules and package-lock.json and then run **npm install** and your package also.

Answer (score 0):

I would install the package using the manual installation instructions, instead of react-native link: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/docs/Install.md